# SAS Output Not Correct

Tags: sas

My concern is about the piece of code I am executing in Odamid. Code is:

```
data b;
if id lt 3 then output b;
input id name $ class $;
datalines;
1 Sudha A
2 Gaurav B
3 Saurabh C
4 Preeti D
;
run;
```

This code is giving me empty numeric dataset with 5 observation.

I am concerned why it is giving me 5 obs. why not not 4?

Comment: The *if* at line 2 is the problem. try splitting it to 2 data steps: data b;
input id name $ class $;.... 
data b1; 
 set b; 
 if id lt 3; 
run;

Comment: @pinegulf no need for 2 data steps, just put the `if` statement after the `input` statement

Comment: @Longfish Right you are.

Comment: Can anyone tell me the order of execution of above code?

Comment: Executable statements are executed in the order they appear.

Answer (score 3):

There are 5 observations output because

- the explicit conditional `output` is before `input`
- conditional is always true

In knowing

- At top of DATA step loop all non-retained variables are reset to
  missing
- `if id < 3` evaluation is `. < 3`, which is true, and `output` occurs
- `input` implicitly checks for end of data condition, if true the step terminates
- `input` parses data line an assigns variable values
- bottom of step reached

In checking

```
data b;
put 'NOTE: ' _n_= 'before if';
if id lt 3 then output b;
put 'NOTE: ' _n_= 'before input';
input id name $ class $;
put 'NOTE: ' _n_= 'before datalines';
datalines;
1 Sudha A
2 Gaurav B
3 Saurabh C
4 Preeti D
;
run;
---------------- LOG -----------------
NOTE: _N_=1 before if
NOTE: _N_=1 before input
NOTE: _N_=1 before datalines
NOTE: _N_=2 before if
NOTE: _N_=2 before input
NOTE: _N_=2 before datalines
NOTE: _N_=3 before if
NOTE: _N_=3 before input
NOTE: _N_=3 before datalines
NOTE: _N_=4 before if
NOTE: _N_=4 before input
NOTE: _N_=4 before datalines
NOTE: _N_=5 before if
NOTE: _N_=5 before input
NOTE: The data set WORK.B has 5 observations and 3 variables.
```

Recommended reading:

- ["A SAS® Programmer's View of the of the SAS Supervisor"](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi22/ADVTUTOR/PAPER34.PDF) Ian Whitlock, Westat Inc., SUGI 22 Conference Proceedings, 1997.

  > **Abstract**
  >
  > This tutorial answers questions like:
  >
  > - As a DATA step programmer, what do I need to know about the SAS supervisor and why?
  > - How does the SAS supervisor process DATA step code?
  > - How does a SAS MERGE work?
  > - What about engines, indexing, and views?
  > - What happens when my DATA step code contains macro variables?
  > - What if my DATA step invokes a macro or is contained in a macro?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 5 observations because the data step iterates five times. On the fifth time it stops when the INPUT statement reads past the end of the data.

All of the variables are empty because you executed the `output` statement before you executed the `input` statement.

Normally SAS adds an implicit `output` statement at the end of your data step.  But when the step already has an explicit `output` statement it does not add one.

Comment: Can any answer if we have multiple where condition in SAS progrm, then why last where output shows?

Comment: @MohitGUpta  If you have a new question post it.  Note that WHERE statements are not executable the way an assignment or IF statement is. It just filters what data makes it into the data step.